# Microsoft account sign in using identity provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I have application in Microsoft Azure. I need to implement user sign in using their already existing Microsoft account. I did the same for google accounts. In google sign in; prompt login and getting the user email, then i'm checking the email in my database. But still i couldn't achieve same scenario to Microsoft account. I tried this with Microsoft Azure OpenId. It say's user is not assigned to the tenent. I need to do this without assigning users to my tenent.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code

Simply i want to allow users to sign and to take their user information.

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) also. It gave following error.

[image]

Comment: HAve you granted return url in your app?

Comment: Yes, i added the redirect URL. Actually i need identity provider authentication. i need some user's info

Comment: When you implemented Google/Microsoft account Sign-in, did you use OWIN and write some code in Startup.Auth.cs file?

Comment: yes i tried it. Mainly i focused to call this as a URL with parameters. Can anyone let me know a direction to achieve this

Comment: Let me provide an answer detailing how we're dealing with this in our application in a bit.

Comment: Ok. It will be a great help for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you're facing two issues: 1) Not getting email back when user signs in using their Microsoft account 2) Invalid request error when using OpenID connect.

**Issue with Microsoft Account Login**

In our application, we also ask users to sign in using their Microsoft account. In order to get the email address back, you actually have to ask for it in form of consent from the user. That is done by specifying appropriate `Scopes` in your request. You would need to provide `wl.emails` scope. Here's how we have configured Microsoft account authentication in our application (in Startup.Auth.cs file).

```
        var microsoftAuthOptions = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Caption = "Microsoft Account",
            ClientId = <your client id>,
            ClientSecret = <your client secret>,
        };
        microsoftAuthOptions.Scope.Add("wl.emails,wl.signin");//Email scope also returns the user name, so that should be fine. We don't need wl.basic.
        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(microsoftAuthOptions);
```

Now when the sign-in process completes, you will see user's email address as one of the claims.

**Issue with Azure AD**

What is happening here is you're redirecting the user to a `common` endpoint (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/<rest of the stuff>`) for authentication and then asking user to grant permissions to your application in that `common` tenant. Because the user doesn't have permission to do so, you're getting this error.

When you need to do is ask the user to provide the URL of Azure AD (e.g. something.onmicrosoft.com) and redirect the user to that for authentication and authorization (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/something.onmicrosoft.com/<rest of the stuff>`). Because now the user is authenticating against a particular Azure AD, they should not get this error if the AD Admin has granted them proper permissions. Please note that the Microsoft account using which user is signing in must be present in that Azure AD and AD Admin has allowed users to grant permissions to 3rd party apps otherwise you will still get this error.

Comment: I did the same thing with owin. I need to add this to custom button in custom view, controller in MVC. I tried URL thing  that you mentioned, it still says unauthorized because i didn't add user to active directory.  Is there any method to grant permission without adding user?

Comment: `Is there any method to grant permission without adding user?` - No. The user **must** be present in the Azure AD.

Comment: Can i do this with Owin?? Why we can't do this like Google identity provider  ? There we are not assigning any user. It prompt any user to sign in using a google account. You helped me to find correct direction

Comment: If all you need to do is have a user sign in with their Microsoft account, then yes. Any time the user need to deal with Azure AD, they would need to be present in that directory.

Comment: Can you please guide me to do this Owin authentication in custom method or in  any Custom Controller in MVC??

Comment: Can you please reach out to me via contact form at gauravmantri.com and we can take this offline? In our application, we're making use of both Startup.Auth.cs and a custom controller for handling post login things. Unfortunately the code I have is so jumbled up that it would need too many changes before I could post here :).